# Top level Function calls in Chrome Flame charts

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-devtools, zone.js

I'm looking at a flame chart of my Angular application. I understand most of it, there are top level XHRs, SetTimeouts,Parse, GC, Script evaluation etc. But there are a few top level 'Function calls', (They seem to be coming from Zone.JS globalZoneAwareCallback.

[image: Flame chart]

Any idea how functions get triggered at the top of the call stack like this?

Comment: Flame chart isn't complete by default and you can display more info: enable "Developer Tools experiments" on `chrome://flags` page, restart, open devtools, open its settings, go to Experiments tab, press Shift key 7 times (ignore and close any OS prompts), then enable items with `timeline` in the label (the one you need is probably `timeline: event initators` and `timeline: show all events`).

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about the Shift key trick. Will try

Comment: DevTools developer advocate here. Have you figured out what caused the callback to execute? Arguably this should be clear from the default recording UI, without needing to enable experiments. I'm trying to figure out where DevTools is coming short here.